# Get Git working on Mac Lion

Tags: macos, xcode

I am running Mac OSX Lion 10.7.3 with Xcode 4.3.2. I have this set up because I needed to get an old iPhone application running.

My problem is I want to install git. When I install the latest version of git on Lion, and run the git command, I get the following error:

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

After research, I discovered that newer git version does not run on Lion. So I tried following these instructions:
https://gist.github.com/digitaljhelms/2931522

However, I get make error:

```
 -bash: make: command not found
```

From what I read online, make should be installed with Xcode, which I have installed. So what is going on here? How can I get a version of git working on Lion?

Comment: Have you try with a package? See here: http://www.devinbaldwin.com/2011/10/25/install-git-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/

Comment: Try installing the appropriate version of Command Line Tools for Xcode.